# UDP Sending frames from OpenCv to EmguCv

Tags: c#, python-2.7, opencv, udp, emgucv

I have got a Raspberry Pi processing images from its raspicam with a Python module.
To simplify I am deleting image processing block codes.

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
from socket import *
import socket
import numpy as np
import sys

class Cam():
    def __init__(self,ip,port):
        self._s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self._address = (ip,port)
        self._quality=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),80]


    def run(self):
        self._cam= PiCamera()
        self._cam.resolution = (640, 480)
        self._cam.framerate = 32
        self._capturer = PiRGBArray(self._cam, size=(640, 480))
        time.sleep(2)

        for frame in self._cam.capture_continuous(self._capturer, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
            try:
                image = frame.array

                # processing

                result, imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image, self._quality)
                data = np.array(imgencode)

                stringData = data.tostring()
                self._s.sendto(stringData,self._address)
                self._capturer.truncate(0)

            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self._cam.close()
                break
```

After that, raspberry sends the image via datagram socket (udp) to my C# program hosted in a PC.
I show you the method that is receiving the bytes from the socket and binding them to a EmguCv `Image` :

```
    private void ReadFrame()
    {
        using (UdpClient socket = new UdpClient(this.camPort))
        {
            try
            {

                while (!end)
                {
                    var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.camPort);
                    byte[] data = socket.Receive(ref remoteEP);

                    this.Frame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(640,480);
                    // Until here it works, and data is correctly received

                    this.Frame.Bytes = data;

                }
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

It works until I try to bind the byte array to the EmguCv `Image` object.
On that line I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in Emgu.CV.World.dll

Because `data` length is lower than what `Frame.Bytes`is expecting.

**How should I build the EmguCv image from bytes?**

**I am also open to other ways of achieving this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, socket architecture was OK.
After testing and testing, I found out a solution.

For the sake of future visitors coming up with the same idea:

Do not use `Image` object of EmguCv. You better want to use Opencv native `Mat` object. In my case, I instantiate it as:

```
this.Mat = new Mat(new Size(640, 480), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
```

And also the obvious part I missed, decode the data with `Imdecode` native method.
Python code results in the same I posted on the question post, but C# method would result in the following:

```
private void ReadFrame()
{
    using (UdpClient socket = new UdpClient(this.camPort))
    {
        try
        {
            while (!end)
            {
                var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.camPort);
                byte[] data = socket.Receive(ref remoteEP);
                Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.Imdecode(data, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.ReducedColor8, this.Mat);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```